# Speed up changing to a folder in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When I change folders (click or navigate to a new folder) in windows explorer i get a quite sizeable delay - between 1 and 2 seconds. I believe it's related to some shell extension. Is there any way to turn them on and off to check which is causing the delay? Is there any other way to speed this up?

Comment: That can be akin to finding a needle in a haystack. Get Nirsoft (.net) Shell Viewx64 and see if you can narrow it down.

Comment: @John Downloaded this tool, disabled everything of type Icon Overlay Handler (Acronis Trueimage, Adobe Coresync, Dropbox, OneDrive) and Thumbnail (Microsoft Office). Also uninstalled AVG (raplaced with Kaspersky). Don't know what exactly was lagging, but it is much faster now, thanks! If you want to add this as an answer I will accept.

Comment: I have provided an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I change folders (click or navigate to a new folder) in windows
> explorer i get a quite sizeable delay - between 1 and 2 seconds. I
> believe it's related to some shell extension.

Shell Extensions are very numerous and finding the appropriate extension or extensions can be time consuming and detailed.

The tool I have used is Shell View / Shell View X64 from Nirsoft.

https://www.nirsoft.net

This has helped me.

I have also (over time) upgraded many tools (Java, WinMerge, WinZip and so on) to their 64-bit versions and that has helped.